# Is it possible to exclude some environment variables from serverless deploy?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm using [Serverless](https://serverless.com/) for deploying my functions to AWS Lambda and [Serverless Dot-Env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dotenv-plugin) to load in environment variables. However it seems there is no way to exclude some of these variables from the deployed Lambda. If you go on the Lambda dashboard on AWS you will find all variables listed on `Environment variables`, but what if I don't want some of them (like the `NODE_ENV` variable) to be there? I tried doing this in my serverless.yml file

```
exclude:
 - ${env:NODE_ENV}
```

But the variable was still there as you can see in the image below
[image]

So is there a way to hide such variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serverless-dot-env` currently does not have a blacklist option but they do have a whitelist option.

Example from https://github.com/colynb/serverless-dotenv-plugin#plugin-options:

```
custom:
  dotenv:
    path: path/to/my/.env (default ./.env)
    basePath: path/to/ (default ./)
    include:
      - AUTH0_CLIENT_ID
      - AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET
```

If you use `include`, only the variables you specified will be included.

### Update: serverless-dotenv-plugin has an exclude option since Feb 2, 2020

Example from https://github.com/colynb/serverless-dotenv-plugin#plugin-options:

```
custom:
  dotenv:
    exclude:
      - NODE_ENV # E.g for Google Cloud Functions, you cannot pass this env variable.
```

Comment: That's bizarre, since such feature shouldn't be hard to code. Anyway thank you, using this configuration worked :) By the way no need to specify `path` and `basePath` if you use defaults .env or .env.{stage}